# Ensure that a dependency used in a background thread is not disposed when the controller disposes?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Say I have a controller, with an action, that calls a non awaited async method on a service that is provided by DI like so:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    public AController(IThisIsAService thisIsAService)
    {
         _thisIsAService= thisIsAService;
    }

    ...

    public IActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        // No await as I don't want to block before returning
        _thisIsAService.DoSomethingAsync();

        return View();
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that my instance of `_thisIsAService` will not be disposed with the end controller lifetime before the call to `_thisIsAService.DoSomethingAsync()` has completed?

Comment: Either `await` the call or register it as a singleton

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Change the design and use the mediator pattern with a background worker (IHostedService).

Comment: To clarify your question, since the answer below appears to suggest safety rather than trying to prevent the controller disposing its contents:  You're specifically wanting to prevent disposal of the object by the Controller, correct?

Comment: @Nikosi does this qualify as XY?  I can see the argument, but I encountered his issue before, and while I did solve it by mediating it to an Azure Function, he isn't asking about his solution, he's asking a question where an answer is what you suggested.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny Yes. Why I say XY is because OP is focusing on the symptoms of current issue when the solution is actually to change the design. Calling it an XY is not a negative thing.

Comment: Your comment `No await as I don't want to block before returning` indicates some misunderstanding of how await works. So this looks like a struggling ephemeral problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I ensure that my instance of _thisIsAService will not be disposed with the end controller lifetime before the call to _thisIsAService.DoSomethingAsync() has completed?

Simply, you can't. You need to `await` the call to ensure that it completes before the service goes out of scope. Not awaiting is not the same thing as "running in the background". It will, but it's just an orphaned thread with knowledge of locals that may or may not continue to exist. If you really want to run something in the background, you need a separate thing, like an `IHostedService`, which you would then queue or schedule the work. That `IHostedService`, then, would be responsible for providing dependencies the work needs like your service.

Comment: Good reference to add https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks